# Laravel - How to Prevent submit until all employee comments are filled in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have project approval application. The employee can can for more than one project at a time. I have successfully written the code for project application, where the employee apply for projects.

Model

```
    class Project extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'projects';

        protected $fillable = [
                  'id',
                  'employee_id',
                  'manager_id',
                  'is_approved',
                  'project_title',
              ]; 

       public function projectcomment(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProjectComment');
       } 

        public function employee()
        {
          return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\HrEmployee','employee_id');
        }  

    }

    class ProjectComment extends Model
    {
       protected $table = 'project_comments';

       protected $fillable = [
                  'id',
                  'project_id',
                  'manager_comment',

              ];

       public function project()
       {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Project','project_id');
       }   
    }
```

Controller

```
    public function manager_employee_all_project_approve(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;    
        $userId = Auth::user()->id;
        $employeeids = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('id')->where('id', $employee->id)->first();
        $employeeid = $employeeids->id;        

        $approved_count = Project::where('employee_id', $id)->count();
        if ($approved_count > 0){
  DB::beginTransaction(); 
        try {   
        $approved_post = Project::where('employee_id', $id)->where('is_approved','!=', 3)
                ->update([
                    'is_approved' => 2                   
                    ]);     
    }
```

view

```
        <div class="row no-print">
            <div class="col-12">
              @if ($incompleteCount)
                  <a href ="{{ route('projects.manager_employee_all_project_approve', ['id' => $project->employee_id])}}" class="btn btn-primary float-left"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Approve</a>

              @endif 
            </div>       
        </div>
```

The manager adds comment on each of the project before he approves the project.

The comment field (manager_comment) is in another table, project_comments. From the Controller above, the manager approves the project (projects) by clicking on submit button and then is_approved is set to 2 (2 is for approve).

However, if the manager has not added comment (manager_comment in project_comments relating to project_id and employee_id), the application should prevent him from clicking the submit button. How do I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Validate in your Controller instead: when the employee click the `submit` button check if it is approved and redirect back with error if it's not approved yet

Comment: are you controlling this on frontend or ?

Comment: You have to need front end and backend validation for this